# Hacer que resultado aparezca al instante en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber como hago para que un resultado aparezca momentaneamente, tengo 2 botones que al presionarse aumenta en 1 el valor, pero necesito que el resultado total aparezca sin necesidad de un "button". 
Este es el Código que tengo:

```js
    var i = 0;
  var x = 0;
  var nota1;
  var nota2;
  function aumento(){
   i = i + 1;
   nota1 = document.getElementById("vot").innerHTML = i;
  }
  function aumento1(){
   x = x + 1;
   nota2 = document.getElementById("vota").innerHTML = x;
  }
            function sumar(){
  var suma = 0;
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML;
  suma = parseInt(nota1)+parseInt(nota2);
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = suma;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="aumento()" value="Valor 1">
 <label id='vot'></label>
 <input type="button" onclick="aumento1()" value="Valor 2">
 <label id='vota'></label><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="sumar()" value="TOTAL">
<div>El resultado es :</div><div onclick="sumar()" id="suma"></div>
```

Pero el resultado no se como hacerlo a modo que sin necesidad de un botón me aparezca, que los sume y muestre de momento...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llama a la función sumar desde dentro de las de aumento. He iniciailizado `nota1` y `nota2` a 0 para evitar errores.

```js
var i = 0;
var x = 0;
var nota1 = 0;
var nota2 = 0;
function aumento(){
  i = i + 1;
  nota1 = document.getElementById("vot").innerHTML = i;
  sumar();
}
function aumento1(){
  x = x + 1;
  nota2 = document.getElementById("vota").innerHTML = x;
  sumar();
}
function sumar(){
  var suma = 0;
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML;
  suma = parseInt(nota1)+parseInt(nota2);
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = suma;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="aumento()" value="Valor 1">
<label id='vot'></label>
<input type="button" onclick="aumento1()" value="Valor 2">
<label id='vota'></label><br>
<input type="button" onclick="sumar()" value="TOTAL">
<div>El resultado es :</div><div onclick="sumar()" id="suma"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta David Silva!

Comment: De nada, te agradecería que la marcaras como respuesta correcta si te ayudó